# How to create jobs in linkedin using job post API?

Tags: api, postman, linkedin-api

I  want to create an interface where I will post job offers and I want whenever I'm posting one it get directly posted in LinkedIn by calling the job posting API but I can't figure it out, can anyone help!

I tried creating an app in LinkedIn and verifying it and find the API test in postman from the documentation but I didn't know the rest!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  "elements": [
    {
      "integrationContext": "urn:li:organization:{{company_id}}",
      "companyApplyUrl": "https://careers.yourcompany.com",
      "externalJobPostingId": "{{external_job_posting_id}}",
      "jobPostingOperationType": "CREATE",
      "title": "Software Developer in Test",
      "description": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.\n",
      "listedAt": {{$timestamp}}000,
      "location": "Sunnyvale, California",
      "categories": [
          "rsch"
      ],
      "industries": [
        "urn:li:industry:55"
      ],
      "skillsDescription": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text",
      "companyJobCode" : "company_{{external_job_posting_id}}",
      "employmentStatus": "FULL_TIME",
      "experienceLevel": "EXECUTIVE",
      "trackingPixelUrl": "http://www.trackingpixellocation.com/pixel.gif",
      "listingType": "BASIC"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is the JSON file that i found